# simple webservice code?

Tags: asp.net

i write a simple webservice code in asp.net when i build the service and run the service it is working fine. when i try to access the webservice it is giving some problem , problem means i am not getting that method (webservice method). After completing writing the webserivce i take a asp.net page (.aspx) and in solution explorer i add a webservices and it is added successfully. but when i adding namespace it is not getting the service name ( i not able to add the namespace of websercice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not exactly sure what could be the problem but you should only need to do the following to use the web service:

```
// Look at what you named your web reference, in my example it is
// called MyWebService. Check your solution explorer for the actual name.
// This is the alias you should be using.
MyWebService.YourWebServiceName ws = new MyWebService.YourWebServiceName();
var result = ws.MyMethod(someparameter);
```

Comment: Ya actually it is localhost now i get my webservice and this is my service...
 localhost.Myservices objMyservice = new localhost.Myservices();

But i am not getting the webmethod when i type like "objMyservice." 
in intellisense i am not getting the webmethod

Comment: Make sure you are selecting the correct object to create and not accidently selecting one of the types.

Comment: Ya Mr.Kelsey i selected wrong one. Now it is working fine my service is working fine thank you very much for response and help